# convert mysql minute function to eloquent command

Tags: php, eloquent

I have this table structure below

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | dtime |
| 1   | 09:00 |
| 2   | 10:00 |
| 3   | 11:00 |
| 4   | 11:07 |
| 5   | 12:00 |
| 6   | 12:08 |
| 7   | 12:10 |
+-----|-------+
```

basically what I want to get only the hourly time. here is my command

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_time WHERE MINUTE(d_time) = 0
```

the command works perfectly but I don't know to to convert to eloquent command

```
$result = DT::where(???)->get();
```

Please help. thanks

Comment: Use whereRaw(). That function lets you enter raw SQL.

Comment: I will that @ryantxr.